# how can I do preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to get data from a site but there are some problems.
I want to change the expression begining with `<div class="phraserec"` and ending with `</div></div>`
how can I do it?

```
$source = "<div class="gwblock" id="1936036"><div class="phraserec"bla bla...</div></div>"
$output = preg_replace('/'. preg_quote('<div class="phraserec" '.'(.*?)'.'</div></div>','/') .'/', '</div>' , $ll);
```

I wanted output;

```
<div class="gwblock" id="1936036"><div class="phraserec"bla bla...</div>
```

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: `preg_quote()` is disabling the special meaning of `(.*?)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you're trying to do. Just get rid of one of the two `</div>` at the end?

Comment: @Toto It seems like he's trying to either parse or create invalid HTML, so DOMDocument won't work.

Comment: @Barmar yes if "phraserec" into "gwblock" i wanted only on "/div" sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to call `preg_quote()`, and it's preventing `(.*?)` from being treated as a pattern. And instead of putting the capture group just around `.*?`, you can put it around everything before the second `</div>`.

```
$output = preg_replace('#(<div class="phraserec".*?</div>)</div>#', '$1', $source);
```

`preg_quote()` is needed when you want to turn dynamic input into a literal value in a regular expression.